# Unable to resolve instance of IMvxViewModelLoader in custom Android ViewPresenter after updating to MvvmCross 6.2.2

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I made a custom Android view presenter which uses the `IMvxViewModelLoader`. Before updating MvvmCross from version 5.7 to 6.2.2 I used to get an instance of 
`IMvxViewModelLoader` by dependency injection:

```
public class CustomPresenter : MvxAndroidViewPresenter
{
    private readonly IMvxViewModelLoader _viewModelLoader;
    private readonly IFragmentTypeLookup _fragmentTypeLookup;
    private Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager _fragmentManager;

    public CustomPresenter(IMvxViewModelLoader viewModelLoader, IFragmentTypeLookup fragmentTypeLookup) : base(new List<Assembly>())
    {
        _fragmentTypeLookup = fragmentTypeLookup;
        _viewModelLoader = viewModelLoader;
    }

    // Other code
}
```

In my `Setup` class which inherits from `MvxAndroidSetup` I override the `IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()` method:

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new App();
    }

    protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new DebugTrace();
    }

    protected override void InitializeIoC()
    {
        base.InitializeIoC();

        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IFragmentTypeLookup>(new FragmentTypeLookup());
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IFileLocationService>(new FileLocationService());
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ISQLitePlatform>(new SQLitePlatformAndroid());
    }

    protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        var presenter = Mvx.IocConstruct<CustomPresenter>();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>(presenter);
        return presenter;
    }

    // Other code
}
```

With the update some changes had to be made to the `protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()` method so I changed it to:

```
protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
{
    var presenter = Mvx.IoCProvider.IoCConstruct<CustomPresenter>();
    Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>(presenter);
    return presenter;
}
```

Running the app now will throw an exception inside the constructor of `CustomPresenter` which indicates that the `IMvxViewModelLoader` instance could not be resolved. I don't register it anywhere but I was assuming MvvmCross did this for me since I didn't register it anywhere before the update. More specifically I thought MvvmCross did this for me when I call `base.InitializeIoC();`.

I also tried to retrieve an instance of the `IMvxViewModelLoader` by changing the `CustomPresenter` constructor into:

```
public CustomPresenter() : base(new List<Assembly>())
{
    _fragmentTypeLookup = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IFragmentTypeLookup>();
    _viewModelLoader = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
}
```

but it has the same result.

I unsuccessfully searched for clues through the update documentation: [Upgrade from 5 to MvvmCross 6](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/upgrading/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-60).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IMvxViewModelLoader` is created after the presenter is created. This is why you are encountering issues with resolving it when you IoC construct your presenter or when  you try to resolve in the ctor of it.

What you can do is to lazy load it *or* get notified by the IoC that the `IMvxViewModelLoader` has been loaded into the IoC.

In the first case you could simply create a Property in your presenter, which checks for null when you use it:

```
private IMvxViewModelLoader _viewModelLoader;
private IMvxViewModelLoader ViewModelLoader
{
    get
    {
        if (_viewModelLoader == null)
            _viewModelLoader = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();

        return _viewModelLoader;
    }
}
```

For getting a call back when `IMvxViewModelLoader` is registered:

```
Mvx.IoCProvider.CallbackWhenRegistered<IMvxViewModelLoader>(loader =>
{
    // do your stuff here when it loads
});
```

Comment: Thank you once again Cheesebaron. How could I've known that the `IMvxViewModelLoader` is created after the presenter is created? Did I miss some documentation, if not, is it relevant enough to create a pull request and add it to the [View Presenter documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/view-presenters)?

Comment: It is kind of documented here: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/advanced/customizing-using-App-and-Setup although this document may be a bit out of date. I looked in the code, specifically in MvxSetup